# Connecting JIRA and MS Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I am .NET developer and new to both JIRA and MS Dynamics API development. Recently I got a task to integrate JIRA and MS Dynamics. Basically I need to update JIRA Issue time tracking Information to Dynamics. And also need to share some Dynamics Information on JIRA.

Possible approaches to solve this problem.

1. Write JIRA plugin to Connect with Dynamics via WEB API. (This approach need Java development Experience)
2. Write Dynamics extension to communicate with JIRA through JIRA web service
3. Write Scheduled task to synchronize JIRA and Dynamics using JIRA and Dynamics web services
4. Develop ASP.NET web site and use JIRA and Dynamics Webhooks to synchronize

I am thinking of write a scheduled task or use Webhooks to achieve this task. Is there any other way to achieve this task? What is the best possible approach to sync JIRA and MS Dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating issues only one way (JIRA to CRM) then you can't do this with CRM plugin. Also I don't see how you could do this with ASP.NET website (I mean without any user action on this site). If you need most current data in CRM then best option would be JIRA plugin if not then sheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

I've more or less always seen people go with #3 when having to sync CRM (usually with ERPs like NAV or SAP). We too code custom programs to be scheduled in order to do the syncing.

Or you could buy Scribe, which allegedly syncs anything with anything... No hands-on experience on that, but I know it's used by big companies so it should work.